# Error: Returned error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: xxxxxxxxx and the sender's account only has: xxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to run a huge test suite(around 50 test cases) using Truffle and after around 18-20 test cases pass I'm getting this error for the remaining test cases. The tests seem to be running fine when they are run individually, the error only comes when the whole test suite is being run to make sure each test case passes. Is there any solution to this, I already tried the mnemonic method where I pass the mnemonic received from truffle and pass it in the config file, that doesn't seem to work as well. Are there any other methods to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Ganache as a test network every test account by default gets a balance of 100ETH.

As Ganache by default funds multiple accounts (10) you could alternative between the accounts.

Another way is to increase the default ETH balance of the test accounts. This can be done by specifying [`default_balance_ether`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/tree/master#options). But for this you need to explicitly spin up ganache and run your tests against the test instance (see https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4382 for more context). There have been some hacks to work around this (e.g. [by Gnosis](https://github.com/gnosis/run-with-testrpc)).